# Is it possible to use multiple docker images in bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have this pipeline file to unittest my project:

```
image: jameslin/python-test

    pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
            script:
              - service mysql start
              - pip install -r requirements/test.txt
              - export DJANGO_CONFIGURATION=Test
              - python manage.py test
```

but is it possible to switch to another docker image to deploy?

```
image: jameslin/python-deploy

    pipelines:
      default:
        - step:
            script: 
              - ansible-playbook deploy
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation saying either Yes or No.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can specify an image for each step. Like that:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        image: node:8.6
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm test
          - npm run build
        artifacts:
          - dist/**
    - step:
        name: Deploy
        image: python:3.5.1
        trigger: manual
        script:
          - python deploy.py
```

Comment: Can I have multiple images in a step only?

Comment: @SuganthanMadhavanPillai afaik that is not possible, each step runs on a single image

Comment: @DmitryZaytsev In this case how to define the deployment?

Comment: One way to utilise multiple images in a single step might be to use services? https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/

Comment: @Mark sadly no.  Atlassian should improve this.

Answer (score 12):

Finally found it:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_stepstep(required)

> step (required) Defines a build execution unit. Steps are executed in
>   the order in which they appear in the pipeline. Currently, each
>   pipeline can have only one step (one for the default pipeline and one
>   for each branch). You can override the main Docker image by specifying
>   an image in a step.

Comment: "You can override the main Docker image by specifying an image in a step." - wheres the code for specifying? :D

Comment: Only issue with using multiple images is that each one still needs to be pulled down and spun up which can eat away at your allotted minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any information saying yes or no either so what I have assumed is that since this image can be configured with all the languages and technology you need I would suggest this method:

1. Create your docker image with all utilities you need for both default and deployment.
2. Use the branching method they show in their examples https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_branchesbranches(optional)
3. Use shell scripts or other scripts to run specific tasks you need and

[image]

```
image: yourusername/your-image

pipelines:
 branches:
  master:
  - step:
      script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - echo "Starting pipelines for master"
        - chmod +x your-task-configs.sh #necessary to get shell script to run in BB Pipelines
        - ./your-task-configs.sh
feature/*:
  - step:
      script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
        - echo "Starting pipelines for feature/*"
        - npm install
        - npm install -g grunt-cli
        - npm install grunt --save-dev
        - grunt build
```